# Bound on euclidean norm

Tags: approximation, normed-spaces

Is it possible to find a suitable lower bound on 
$$\left|\left(tM+\sum_{k=2}^\infty\frac{(tM)^k}{k!}\right)\cdot b\right|$$
for $M$ as $n \times n$ matrix, $b$ as $1 \times n$ vector and for all $t$ in the form of
$$|tAb|-c|b|$$ 
with appropriate $c$?

Or are there other practical approximations on the upper equation?

Thanks!

Comment: Why did you distinguish the term $k=1$ from the sum? The expression in brackets is by the way $\mathrm e^{tM}-I$ where $I$ is the identity matrix of the dimension $n\times n$. Would you also clarify, why are you interested in such bounds?

Comment: There is no particular reason why I distinguish k=1. I thought it would be helpful, because I wan to calculate the interception point of the upper function f(t)=|...| with an onther curve. I hoped to seperate the t by distinguishing k=1. Note, the solution should be less than or equal the upper function.